# ASIHttpRequest Reachability version

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, reachability

At the moment I'm developing a network client software for iPhone/iPad. I'm using ASIHttpRequest library to interact with our web service.

I've noticed the latest version of ASIHttpRequest contains a bit outdated Reachability API, namely "2.0.4ddg". The latest version on apple.com is 2.2.

Is it a good idea to upgrade the Reachability component that's bundled with ASIHttpRequest library? The software I'm developing must work on iOS 4.2.1 and later.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your full question, however the 2.0.4ddg version contains a number of enhancements over the Apple 2.0 version, as listed here:

http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24

I've not looked at what Apple changed between 2.0 and 2.2 though.

If I recall correctly, the ddg version has slight API changes compared to the Apple one, so it's not a drop in replacement.